# Mafia (party game) helper

Tags: android, python

Mafia game helper is very simple. It allows me to input the number of roles(mafia, detective, innocents etc.) first. Then each player will input their name and the computer will randomly choose a role for him/her. And the first player pass the computer to the next player and so on. At the end, computer will generate a list.

Something like:

- Tom : Mafia
- John : detective

Here is my code:

```
import random
role=[]
k = input("Number of mafia: ")
p = input("Number of detective: ")
n = input("Number of innocent: ")

---magic---

random.shuffle(role)

player = []
i=0
while True:
    name = raw_input()
    player.append(name)
    print role[i]
    i += 1
```

I have two problems in programming this.

1. How can I make a list called 'role' with k 'mafia' , and p 'detective'? For example: if k = 3, p = 1, n = 1, then the list 'role' will be ['mafia', 'mafia', 'mafia', 'detective', 'innocent']. I know that I can do it with for loop but is there any easy way (a.k.a magic) to do this?
2. There is a very serious bug as now the second player can see what role is assigned to the first player. How can I solve this and make no player could see this? But I have to keep the results since I have to make a list at the end as I mentioned.

My friends love to play this game so much so I want to surprise them by this program!
Thank you for everyone read this. Have a good day =]

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your list generation problem

```
>>> k = 3
>>> p = 1
>>> n = 2
>>> roles = ['mafia']*k + ['detective']*p + ['innocent']*n
>>> roles
['mafia', 'mafia', 'mafia', 'detective', 'innocent', 'innocent']
```

One method to randomly assign roles

```
from random import shuffle
shuffle(roles)
names = ['bob', 'steve', 'tom', 'jon', 'alex', 'mike']
players = dict(zip(names,roles))

>>> players
{'mike': 'innocent',
 'alex': 'mafia',
 'steve': 'mafia',
 'tom': 'mafia',
 'bob': 'detective',
 'jon': 'innocent'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could clear the output after assigning each person? this should now clear

```
import random
import os
k = input("Number of mafia: ")
p = input("Number of detective: ")
n = input("Number of innocent: ")

roles = ['mafia']*k + p*['detective'] + n * ['innocent']

random.shuffle(roles)

while roles:
    print 'name:',
    name = raw_input()
    print 'you are a ' + roles.pop(0)
    print 'clear?'
    clear = raw_input()
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
```

or alternatively you could write the roles out to individual files which might work better

```
import random
import os
k = input("Number of mafia: ")
p = input("Number of detective: ")
n = input("Number of innocent: ")

roles = ['mafia']*k + p*['detective'] + n * ['innocent']

random.shuffle(roles)

people = []

path = ''

while roles:
    print 'name:',
    name = raw_input()
    while name in people:
        print 'name already_taken please take new name'
        name = raw_input()
    people.append(name)
    person_file = open(os.path.join(path,'%s.txt') % (name,),'w')
    person_file.write('you are a %s' % (roles.pop(0),))
    person_file.close()
```

Comment: Number of mafia: 3
Number of detective: 1
Number of innocent: 2
name: tom
you are a mafia
clear?
tom
[2J
name: z
you are a detective
clear?
v
[2J
name: q
you are a mafia
clear?
b
[2J
name:

Comment: this is the output and it means that the next player can see the previous player assigned role. How to fix this? =]

Comment: edited to add better clearing and another alternative